# How do i read this json and change it to dictionary in swift?

Tags: json, swift

Here's my json:

```
{
  "content": {
    "id": "faa",
    "properties": [],
    "type": "DOCUMENT",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "b64",
        "properties": [],
        "type": "SECTION",
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {
                "children": [],
                "id": "316",
                "properties": [],
                "type": "RICH-TEXT-STRING",
                "attributes": [
                  [
                    "PARAGRAPH_STYLES",
                    [
                      {
                        "attribute": "normal",
                        "charIndex": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                ],
                "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
              }
            ],
            "id": "daac",
            "properties": [],
            "type": "RICH-TEXT-FRAME",
            "annotation": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "styleSheet": {
      "children": [],
      "id": "7bc",
      "properties": [],
      "type": "STYLE-SHEET",
      "stylesMap": [
        [
          "heading1",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "heading1",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": true,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 28,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Heading 1"
          }
        ],
        [
          "heading2",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "heading2",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": true,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 20,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Heading 2"
          }
        ],
        [
          "normal",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "normal",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": false,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 17,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Normal"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "RDFB",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public typealias StyleID = String

enum PredefinedParagraphStyleID: String, Codable {
  case blockquote = "blockquote"
  case bullets = "bullets"
  case heading1 = "heading1"
  case heading2 = "heading2"
  case listItem = "listItem"
  case numbered = "numbered"
  case normal = "normal"
}

public enum ParagraphAlignmentStyle: String, Codable {
  case left = "H_LEFT"
  case center = "H_CENTER"
  case right = "H_RIGHT"
  case justified = "H_JUSTIFIED"
}

public enum HorizontalAlignmentStyle: String, Codable {
  case left = "LEFT"
  case center = "CENTER"
  case right = "RIGHT"
  case justified = "JUSTIFIED"
}

public struct SupportedStyleProperties: Codable, Equatable {
  public init(align: ParagraphAlignmentStyle? = nil, background: String? = nil, bold: Bool = false, borderStart: String? = nil, doubleunderline: Bool = false, fontColor: String? = nil,
              fontFamily: String? = nil, fontSize: Int? = nil, fontWeight: Int? = nil, hAlignment: HorizontalAlignmentStyle? = nil, horizontalRuleAbove: Bool = false,
              horizontalRuleBelow: Bool = false, isBlockQuote: Bool = false, isList: Bool = false,
              isOrdered: Bool = false, italic: Bool = false, lineHeight: Float? = nil,
              listStyleType: String? = nil, marginBottom: Float? = nil, marginStart: Float? = nil,
              marginTop: Float? = nil, paddingBottom: Float? = nil, paddingEnd: Float? = nil,
              paddingStart: Float? = nil, paddingTop: Float? = nil, strikethrough: Bool = false,
              underline: Bool = false, vAlignment: String? = nil,
              whiteSpace: UEWhiteSpaceType? = nil, writingDirection: WritingDirection? = nil) {
    self.align = align
    self.background = background
    self.bold = bold
    self.borderStart = borderStart
    self.doubleunderline = doubleunderline
    self.fontColor = fontColor
    self.fontFamily = fontFamily
    self.fontSize = fontSize
    self.fontWeight = fontWeight
    self.hAlignment = hAlignment
    self.horizontalRuleAbove = horizontalRuleAbove
    self.horizontalRuleBelow = horizontalRuleBelow
    self.isBlockQuote = isBlockQuote
    self.isList = isList
    self.isOrdered = isOrdered
    self.italic = italic
    self.lineHeight = lineHeight
    self.listStyleType = listStyleType
    self.marginBottom = marginBottom
    self.marginStart = marginStart
    self.marginTop = marginTop
    self.paddingBottom = paddingBottom
    self.paddingEnd = paddingEnd
    self.paddingStart = paddingStart
    self.paddingTop = paddingTop
    self.strikethrough = strikethrough
    self.underline = underline
    self.vAlignment = vAlignment
    self.whiteSpace = whiteSpace
    self.writingDirection = writingDirection
  }
  public let align: ParagraphAlignmentStyle?
  public let background: String?
  public var bold: Bool = false
  public let borderStart: String?
  public var doubleunderline: Bool = false
  public let fontColor: String?
  public let fontFamily: String?
  public let fontSize: Int?
  public let fontWeight: Int?
  public let hAlignment: HorizontalAlignmentStyle?
  public var horizontalRuleAbove: Bool = false
  public var horizontalRuleBelow: Bool = false
  public var isBlockQuote: Bool = false
  public var isList: Bool = false
  public var isOrdered: Bool = false
  public var italic: Bool = false
  public let lineHeight: Float?
  public let listStyleType: String?
  public let marginBottom: Float?
  public let marginStart: Float?
  public let marginTop: Float?
  public let paddingBottom: Float?
  public let paddingEnd: Float?
  public let paddingStart: Float?
  public let paddingTop: Float?
  public var strikethrough: Bool = false
  public var underline: Bool = false
  public let vAlignment: String?
  public let whiteSpace: WhiteSpaceType?
  public let writingDirection: WritingDirection?

  public static func == (lhs: SupportedStyleProperties, rhs: SupportedStyleProperties) -> Bool {
    return lhs.align == rhs.align &&
    lhs.background == rhs.background &&
    lhs.bold == rhs.bold &&
    lhs.borderStart == rhs.borderStart &&
    lhs.doubleunderline == rhs.doubleunderline &&
    lhs.fontColor == rhs.fontColor &&
    lhs.fontFamily == rhs.fontFamily &&
    lhs.fontSize == rhs.fontSize &&
    lhs.fontWeight == rhs.fontWeight &&
    lhs.hAlignment == rhs.hAlignment &&
    lhs.horizontalRuleAbove == rhs.horizontalRuleAbove &&
    lhs.horizontalRuleBelow == rhs.horizontalRuleBelow &&
    lhs.isBlockQuote == rhs.isBlockQuote &&
    lhs.isList == rhs.isList &&
    lhs.isOrdered == rhs.isOrdered &&
    lhs.italic == rhs.italic &&
    lhs.lineHeight == rhs.lineHeight &&
    lhs.listStyleType == rhs.listStyleType &&
    lhs.marginBottom == rhs.marginBottom &&
    lhs.marginStart == rhs.marginStart &&
    lhs.marginTop == rhs.marginTop &&
    lhs.paddingBottom == rhs.paddingBottom &&
    lhs.paddingEnd == rhs.paddingEnd &&
    lhs.paddingStart == rhs.paddingStart &&
    lhs.paddingTop == rhs.paddingTop &&
    lhs.strikethrough == rhs.strikethrough &&
    lhs.underline == rhs.underline &&
    lhs.vAlignment == rhs.vAlignment &&
    lhs.whiteSpace == rhs.whiteSpace &&
    lhs.writingDirection == rhs.writingDirection
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case align
    case background
    case bold
    case borderStart
    case doubleunderline
    case fontColor
    case fontFamily
    case fontSize
    case fontWeight
    case hAlignment
    case horizontalRuleAbove
    case horizontalRuleBelow
    case isBlockQuote
    case isList
    case isOrdered
    case italic
    case lineHeight
    case listStyleType
    case marginBottom
    case marginStart
    case marginTop
    case paddingBottom
    case paddingEnd
    case paddingStart
    case paddingTop
    case strikethrough
    case underline
    case vAlignment
    case whiteSpace
    case writingDirection
  }
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SupportedStyleProperties.CodingKeys.self)
    self.align = try container.decodeIfPresent(ParagraphAlignmentStyle.self, forKey: .align)
    self.background = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .background)
    self.bold = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .bold) ?? false
    self.borderStart = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .borderStart)
    self.doubleunderline = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .doubleunderline) ?? false
    self.fontColor = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fontColor)
    self.fontWeight = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .fontWeight)
    self.fontFamily = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fontFamily)
    self.fontSize = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .fontSize)
    self.hAlignment = try container.decode(HorizontalAlignmentStyle.self, forKey: .hAlignment)
    self.horizontalRuleBelow = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .horizontalRuleBelow) ?? false
    self.horizontalRuleAbove = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .horizontalRuleAbove) ?? false
    self.isBlockQuote = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isBlockQuote) ?? false
    self.isList = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isList) ?? false
    self.isOrdered = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isOrdered) ?? false
    self.italic = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .italic) ?? false
    self.lineHeight = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .lineHeight)
    self.listStyleType = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .listStyleType)
    self.marginBottom = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .marginBottom)
    self.marginTop = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .marginTop)
    self.marginStart = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .marginStart)
    self.paddingBottom = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .paddingBottom)
    self.paddingStart = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .paddingStart)
    self.paddingEnd = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .paddingEnd)
    self.paddingTop = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .paddingTop)
    self.strikethrough = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .strikethrough) ?? false
    self.underline = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .underline) ?? false
    self.vAlignment = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .vAlignment)
    self.whiteSpace = try container.decodeIfPresent(WhiteSpaceType.self, forKey: .whiteSpace)
    self.writingDirection = try container.decodeIfPresent(WritingDirection.self, forKey: .writingDirection)
  }
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(align, forKey: .align)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(background, forKey: .background)
    try container.encode(bold, forKey: .bold)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(borderStart, forKey: .borderStart)
    try container.encode(doubleunderline, forKey: .doubleunderline)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(fontColor, forKey: .fontColor)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(fontWeight, forKey: .fontWeight)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(fontFamily, forKey: .fontFamily)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(fontSize, forKey: .fontSize)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(hAlignment, forKey: .hAlignment)
    try container.encode(horizontalRuleBelow, forKey: .horizontalRuleBelow)
    try container.encode(horizontalRuleAbove, forKey: .horizontalRuleAbove)
    try container.encode(isBlockQuote, forKey: .isBlockQuote)
    try container.encode(isList, forKey: .isList)
    try container.encode(isOrdered, forKey: .isOrdered)
    try container.encode(italic, forKey: .italic)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(lineHeight, forKey: .lineHeight)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(listStyleType, forKey: .listStyleType)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(marginBottom, forKey: .marginBottom)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(marginTop, forKey: .marginTop)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(marginStart, forKey: .marginStart)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(paddingBottom, forKey: .paddingBottom)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(paddingStart, forKey: .paddingStart)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(paddingEnd, forKey: .paddingEnd)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(paddingTop, forKey: .paddingTop)
    try container.encode(strikethrough, forKey: .strikethrough)
    try container.encode(underline, forKey: .underline)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(vAlignment, forKey: .vAlignment)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(whiteSpace, forKey: .whiteSpace)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(writingDirection, forKey: .writingDirection)
  }
}

public enum WhiteSpaceType: String, Codable {
  case normal = "normal"
  case nowrap = "nowrap"
  case pre = "pre"
  case preWrap = "pre-wrap"
  case preLine = "pre-line"
  case breakSpace = "break-space"
}

public enum WritingDirection: String, Codable {
  case left = "ltr"
  case natural = "natural"
  case right = "rtl"
}

public struct Style: Codable {
  public init(id: StyleID, isAnonymousStyle: Bool = false, followingStyle: StyleID, parentParagraphStyle: StyleID?, properties: StyleProperties, title: String? = nil) {
    self.id = id
    self.isAnonymousStyle = isAnonymousStyle
    self.followingStyle = followingStyle
    self.parentParagraphStyle = parentParagraphStyle
    self.properties = properties
    self.title = title
  }
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case isAnonymousStyle
    case followingStyle
    case parentParagraphStyle
    case properties
    case title
  }
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Style.CodingKeys.self)
    self.properties = try container.decode(StyleProperties.self, forKey: .properties)
    self.title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
    self.isAnonymousStyle = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isAnonymousStyle) ?? false
    self.followingStyle = try container.decode(StyleID.self, forKey: .followingStyle)
    self.parentParagraphStyle = try container.decode(StyleID.self, forKey: .parentParagraphStyle)
    self.id = try container.decode(StyleID.self, forKey: .id)
  }
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(properties, forKey: .properties)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(title, forKey: .title)
    try container.encode(isAnonymousStyle, forKey: .isAnonymousStyle)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(parentParagraphStyle, forKey: .parentParagraphStyle)
    try container.encode(followingStyle, forKey: .followingStyle)
  }
  var id: StyleID
  var isAnonymousStyle: Bool = false
  var followingStyle: StyleID
  let parentParagraphStyle: StyleID?
  public var properties: StyleProperties
  var title: String?
}

public enum StylePropertyType: String, Codable {
  case paragraph = "PARAGRAPH"
  case list = "LIST"
  case listItem = "LIST_ITEM"
  case character = "CHARACTER"
  case voImage = "VISUAL_OBJECT_IMAGE"
  case voVideo = "VISUAL_OBJECT_VIDEO"
  case voTable = "VISUAL_OBJECT_TABLE"
  case voRichTextFrame = "VISUAL_OBJECT_RICH_TEXT_FRAME"
}

public struct StyleProperties: Codable, Equatable {
  let type: StylePropertyType
  public let properties: SupportedStyleProperties

  public init(type: StylePropertyType, properties: SupportedStyleProperties =
              SupportedStyleProperties(
                align: nil,
                background: nil,
                bold: false,
                borderStart: nil,
                doubleunderline: false,
                fontColor: nil,
                fontFamily: nil,
                fontSize: nil,
                fontWeight: nil,
                hAlignment: nil,
                horizontalRuleAbove: false,
                horizontalRuleBelow: false,
                isBlockQuote: false,
                isList: false,
                isOrdered: false,
                italic: false,
                lineHeight: nil,
                listStyleType: nil,
                marginBottom: nil,
                marginStart: nil,
                marginTop: nil,
                paddingBottom: nil,
                paddingEnd: nil,
                paddingStart: nil,
                paddingTop: nil,
                strikethrough: false,
                underline: false,
                vAlignment: nil,
                whiteSpace: nil,
                writingDirection: nil
              )
  ) {
    self.type = type
    self.properties = properties
  }
  public static func == (rhs: StyleProperties, lhs: StyleProperties) -> Bool {
    return rhs.type == lhs.type && rhs.properties == lhs.properties
  }
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case properties
    case type
  }
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: StyleProperties.CodingKeys.self)
    self.properties = try container.decode(SupportedStyleProperties.self, forKey: .properties)
    self.type = try container.decode(StylePropertyType.self, forKey: .type)
  }
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(properties, forKey: .properties)
    try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
  }
}

public enum PredefinedCharacterStyle: String {
  case bold = "bold"
  case underline = "underline"
  case doubleUnderline = "doubleunderline"
  case strikethrough = "strikethrough"
  case italic = "italic"
}
```

This is how I parse the JSON which isn't working: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

```
override func fromJson(JsonNode: JsonNode) throws -> StyleSheet {
      guard let objectNode = try super.fromJson(JsonNode: JsonNode) as? StyleSheet
      else {
        throw Errors.unrecoverableError(message: "Could not create")
      }

      guard let stylesMapArray = JsonNode.stylesMap else {
        throw Errors.unrecoverableError(message: "stylesMap is missing")
      }
      guard let first = stylesMapArray.first else {
        throw UEErrors.unrecoverableError(message: "No items")
      }
      objectNode.stylesMap = first

      return objectNode
    }
```

So I think I'm reading stylesMap wrong.The format may be because json has an array of dictionary while the stylesMap is a dict.But I'm not sure how do I proceed.

Comment: Paste your JSON into app.quicktype.io and compare what it generates to what you have.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with the built in `Codable` protocol, are you using some 3rd party library for decoding json?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No

Comment: @jnpdx both are same.

Comment: Well you haven't posted any decoding code and your struct clearly doesn't fit the json structure and why are you talking about some `stylesMap`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have updated the struct and I'm talking about stylesMap because I think that part of JSON is not reading properly.

Comment: Since you haven't posted the code where you decode the json I can only assume you do `print(error.localizedDescription)`, change that to `print(error)` instead and you will get a much more detailed error message.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for that hint, Now I'm getting this error : [CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "styleSheet", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "stylesMap", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Style> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: And what does that tell you?

Comment: Hint, it has to do with `properties`. Once you have sorted that out, you will face a new error so you have some work ahead of you.

Comment: Does it mean this decode is wrong: stylesMap = try container.decodeIfPresent([[StyleID: Style]].self, forKey: .stylesMap)

Comment: `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Style].self, from: data)`, that's how I did it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson does changing array of dictionary to dictionary work? If yes, how do i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the app [Boop](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/boop/id1518425043?mt=12), available for free on the Mac AppStore.
It probably can format your json right, worth a try. Here is the formatted version, something changed, but I don't know exactly what:

```
{
"content": {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "annotation": null,
            "children": [
              {
                "attributes": [
                  [
                    "PARAGRAPH_STYLES",
                    [
                      {
                        "attribute": "normal",
                        "charIndex": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                ],
                "children": [],
                "id": "316",
                "properties": [],
                "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "type": "RICH-TEXT-STRING"
              }
            ],
            "id": "daac",
            "properties": [],
            "type": "RICH-TEXT-FRAME"
          }
        ],
        "id": "b64",
        "properties": [],
        "type": "SECTION"
      }
    ],
    "id": "faa",
    "properties": [],
    "styleSheet": {
      "children": [],
      "id": "7bc",
      "properties": [],
      "stylesMap": [
        [
          "heading1",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "heading1",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": true,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 28,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Heading 1"
          }
        ],
        [
          "heading2",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "heading2",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": true,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 20,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Heading 2"
          }
        ],
        [
          "normal",
          {
            "followingStyle": "normal",
            "id": "normal",
            "properties": {
              "align": "H_LEFT",
              "bold": false,
              "fontColor": "rgb(5,5,5)",
              "fontFamily": "inherit",
              "fontSize": 17,
              "italic": false,
              "strikethrough": false,
              "type": "PARAGRAPH",
              "underline": false
            },
            "title": "Normal"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "type": "STYLE-SHEET"
    },
    "type": "DOCUMENT"
  },
  "type": "RDFB",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```